# Kodein + Ktor = mutation attempt of frozen kotlin.collections.HashMap - why?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor, kotlin-native, kodein

I have been struggling with this exception for couple of days recently.

I have a kotlin multiplatform project with these dependencies:

- kotlin=1.5.10
- kodein=7.6.0
- ktor=1.6.0 (uses kotlin coroutines 1.5.0-native-mt internally)

And I have been getting mentioned exception while trying to use httpClient in native:

```
    at kotlin.Throwable#<init>(/Users/teamcity3/buildAgent/work/290aee0e088a1666/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/Throwable.kt:23)
    at kotlin.Exception#<init>(/Users/teamcity3/buildAgent/work/290aee0e088a1666/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/Exceptions.kt:23)
    at kotlin.RuntimeException#<init>(/Users/teamcity3/buildAgent/work/290aee0e088a1666/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/Exceptions.kt:34)
    at kotlin.native.concurrent.InvalidMutabilityException#<init>(/Users/teamcity3/buildAgent/work/290aee0e088a1666/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/native/concurrent/Freezing.kt:22)
    at <global>.ThrowInvalidMutabilityException(/Users/teamcity3/buildAgent/work/290aee0e088a1666/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/native/concurrent/Internal.kt:93)
    at <global>.MutationCheck(Unknown Source)
    at kotlin.collections.HashMap.<set-length>#internal(/Users/teamcity3/buildAgent/work/290aee0e088a1666/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/collections/HashMap.kt:16)
    at kotlin.collections.HashMap#addKey(/Users/teamcity3/buildAgent/work/290aee0e088a1666/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/collections/HashMap.kt:292)
    at kotlin.collections.HashMap#put(/Users/teamcity3/buildAgent/work/290aee0e088a1666/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/collections/HashMap.kt:68)
    at org.kodein.di.internal.DITreeImpl#find(/Users/runner/work/Kodein-DI/Kodein-DI/kodein-di/src/commonMain/kotlin/org/kodein/di/internal/DITreeImpl.kt:132)
    at org.kodein.di.DITree#find$default(/Users/runner/work/Kodein-DI/Kodein-DI/kodein-di/src/commonMain/kotlin/org/kodein/di/DITree.kt:36)
    at org.kodein.di.internal.DIContainerImpl#factory(/Users/runner/work/Kodein-DI/Kodein-DI/kodein-di/src/commonMain/kotlin/org/kodein/di/internal/DIContainerImpl.kt:158)
    at org.kodein.di.DIContainer#factory$default(/Users/runner/work/Kodein-DI/Kodein-DI/kodein-di/src/commonMain/kotlin/org/kodein/di/DIContainer.kt:32)
    at org.kodein.di.DIContainer#provider(/Users/runner/work/Kodein-DI/Kodein-DI/kodein-di/src/commonMain/kotlin/org/kodein/di/DIContainer.kt:76)
    at org.kodein.di.DIContainer#provider$default(/Users/runner/work/Kodein-DI/Kodein-DI/kodein-di/src/commonMain/kotlin/org/kodein/di/DIContainer.kt:75)
    at org.kodein.di.internal.DirectDIBaseImpl#Instance(/Users/runner/work/Kodein-DI/Kodein-DI/kodein-di/src/commonMain/kotlin/org/kodein/di/internal/DirectDIImpl.kt:30)
    at InvalidMutabilitySampleTest.<init>$lambda-6$lambda-5$lambda-4$lambda-3$lambda-2#internal(/Users/r.juszczyk/StudioProjects/lmhu-multiplatform-app/MultiplatformApp/src/iosTest/kotlin/InvalidMutabilitySampleTest.kt:26)
    at InvalidMutabilitySampleTest.$<init>$lambda-6$lambda-5$lambda-4$lambda-3$lambda-2$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$3.invoke#internal(/Users/r.juszczyk/StudioProjects/lmhu-multiplatform-app/MultiplatformApp/src/iosTest/kotlin/InvalidMutabilitySampleTest.kt:25)
    at InvalidMutabilitySampleTest.$<init>$lambda-6$lambda-5$lambda-4$lambda-3$lambda-2$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$3.$<bridge-UNNN>invoke(/Users/r.juszczyk/StudioProjects/lmhu-multiplatform-app/MultiplatformApp/src/iosTest/kotlin/InvalidMutabilitySampleTest.kt:25)
    at io.ktor.client.HttpClientConfig.install$<anonymous>_1#internal(/Users/administrator/Documents/agent/work/8d547b974a7be21f/ktor-client/ktor-client-core/common/src/io/ktor/client/HttpClientConfig.kt:69)
    at io.ktor.client.HttpClientConfig.$install$<anonymous>_1$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$17.invoke#internal(/Users/administrator/Documents/agent/work/8d547b974a7be21f/ktor-client/ktor-client-core/common/src/io/ktor/client/HttpClientConfig.kt:65)
    at io.ktor.client.HttpClientConfig.$install$<anonymous>_1$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$17.$<bridge-UNNN>invoke(/Users/administrator/Documents/agent/work/8d547b974a7be21f/ktor-client/ktor-client-core/common/src/io/ktor/client/HttpClientConfig.kt:65)
    at io.ktor.client.features.json.JsonFeature.Feature#prepare(/Users/administrator/Documents/agent/work/8d547b974a7be21f/ktor-client/ktor-client-features/ktor-client-json/common/src/io/ktor/client/features/json/JsonFeature.kt:129)
    at io.ktor.client.HttpClientConfig.install$<anonymous>_1-2#internal(/Users/administrator/Documents/agent/work/8d547b974a7be21f/ktor-client/ktor-client-core/common/src/io/ktor/client/HttpClientConfig.kt:77)
    at io.ktor.client.HttpClientConfig.$install$<anonymous>_1-2$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$18.invoke#internal(/Users/administrator/Documents/agent/work/8d547b974a7be21f/ktor-client/ktor-client-core/common/src/io/ktor/client/HttpClientConfig.kt:74)
    at io.ktor.client.HttpClientConfig.$install$<anonymous>_1-2$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$18.$<bridge-UNNN>invoke(/Users/administrator/Documents/agent/work/8d547b974a7be21f/ktor-client/ktor-client-core/common/src/io/ktor/client/HttpClientConfig.kt:74)
    at io.ktor.client.HttpClientConfig#install(/Users/administrator/Documents/agent/work/8d547b974a7be21f/ktor-client/ktor-client-core/common/src/io/ktor/client/HttpClientConfig.kt:97)
    at io.ktor.client.HttpClient#<init>(/Users/administrator/Documents/agent/work/8d547b974a7be21f/ktor-client/ktor-client-core/common/src/io/ktor/client/HttpClient.kt:172)
    at io.ktor.client.HttpClient#<init>(/Users/administrator/Documents/agent/work/8d547b974a7be21f/ktor-client/ktor-client-core/common/src/io/ktor/client/HttpClient.kt:81)
    at io.ktor.client#HttpClient(/Users/administrator/Documents/agent/work/8d547b974a7be21f/ktor-client/ktor-client-core/common/src/io/ktor/client/HttpClient.kt:43)
```

I managed to reproduce that crash in a test:

```
class InvalidMutabilitySampleTest {
    val di = DI {
        import(DI.Module("Some Module") {
            bind<Json>() with provider {
                Json {
                    prettyPrint = true
                    isLenient = true
                }
            }

            bind<HttpClient>() with provider {
                HttpClient{
                    install(JsonFeature) {
                        serializer = KotlinxSerializer(instance())
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }

    val httpClient: HttpClient by di.instance()

    @Test
    fun invalidMutabilityTest() {
        println(httpClient)
    }

}
```

I also managed to fix it by changing:

```
HttpClient{
   install(JsonFeature) {
      serializer = KotlinxSerializer(instance())
   }
}
```

to:

```
val json = instance<Json>()
HttpClient{
   install(JsonFeature) {
      serializer = KotlinxSerializer(json)
   }
}
```

Then I noticed that HttpClient does a very specific thing - it freezes itself in the init block.
I managed to reproduce it with this sample code:

```
class FrozenConstructor(val block: ()->Unit) {
    init {
        freeze()
    }
}

class InvalidMutabilitySampleTest2 {
    val di = DI {
        import(DI.Module("Some Module") {
            bind<String>() with provider {
                "lolo"
            }

            bind<FrozenConstructor>() with provider {
                FrozenConstructor{
                    instance<String>()
                }
            }
        })
    }

    val frozenConstructor: FrozenConstructor by di.instance()

    @Test
    fun invalidMutabilityTest() {
        println(frozenConstructor)
    }
}
```

So my theory is following:

1. kodein tries to provide `FrozenConstructor` class
2. `FrozenConstructor` is created and it freezes itself, and its member which references kodein
3. kodein tries to cache provided dependency and try to mutate internal `MutableMap` which is frozen and everything crashes

Can someone confirm that this is more or less correct , and correct me if not?

And also can you guys suggest the best way of handling it, and other pitfalls which are waiting there?

Is it a kodein bug?

Why kodein has to store something in a mutable map if I am using `with provider` not `with singleton` ?

Comment: However, even if you use a provider or factory, Kodein-DI might store the references to those factories in some cases.

Comment: I faced with the similar issue with Koin. I think that's not the Kodein | Koin issue. My config was like kotlin 1.6.10 (coroutines 1.6.0-native-mt), koin 3.2, ktor 1.6.8. The same solution helped me too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you've pretty much figured it out. Ktor freezes itself and all of its configuration in order to ensure that it can be used across threads in Kotlin/Native. Kodein assumes you will only ever touch it from one thread and is not safe to freeze. (Whether that's a limitation, a bug, or a design flaw is maybe up for interpretation.)

To work around these issues, you want to avoid accidentally capturing `this` references in your `HttpClient` configuration that refer to Kodein internals. A good way to do this is to grab instances from DI in helper variables outside the `HttpClient` lambda, as you've discovered.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Imo kodein should call `ensureNeverFrozen()` internally so it throws `FreezingException` instead of `InvalidMutabilityException` - maybe it could be easier to find a bug this way.

Comment: Indeed, this could be easier to spot such errors. I created an issue to follow this action https://github.com/Kodein-Framework/Kodein-DI/issues/371

Comment: That's a limitation by design. We chose not to invest the time and effort required to lift that limitation, since Jetbrains is doing that work for us... https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/05/kotlin-native-memory-management-update/

Answer (score 3):

You are correct.
`FrozenConstructor` freezes itself, and therefore its `block` property, which, as a lambda, freezes all its captures, which includes the DI container.

Kodein-DI does not support freezing (and therefore native multi-threading).
The decision has been made not to invest in making it compatible with native multi-thrading since JB has announced working on a new GC.